# When does function order matter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand that JS does a pre-compilation of functions before it executes code.  So function order does not matter.  But, function order somehow becomes a problem when linking *.js files.

For example,

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Personal/MyJScript.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        hello();
        afterCall();
        hello2(); //fails, defined in MyJScript2.js

    });

    function afterCall() {
        alert('inline function defined after call');
    }
</script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Personal/MyJScript2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In the code above, the function `hello2()` is defined in a file that is linked after the call is defined. The call fails.  So, intuitively I assume now function order *does* matter in this case.

Considering I perform `$(document).ready`, the document should be as ready as it gets.  So, why does this happen?

---

As requested, here is the client side HTML

```
<body>
    <script src="/Scripts/Personal/MyJScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        hello();
        afterCall();
        hello2(); //fails

    });

    function afterCall() {
        alert('inline function defined after call');
    }
</script>

<script src="/Scripts/Personal/MyJScript2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Where in your overall HTML do those `<script>` tags appear?  In the `<head>`?

Comment: It would appear that each *.js file is processed completely before the next one begins processing.

Comment: As your `<script>` tags are in the body, the `$(document).ready` is executed before the MyJScript2.js is loaded.

Comment: is it correctly loading in the myScript.js file? I have done that before lol always makes me feel stupid

Comment: I think this should work as expected. Even though `$(document).ready` is executed before the second script is loaded, the callback should not be executed until the whole initial DOM is known (i.e. the parser reached a closing `</html>` tag or eof). I think the problem must be in the MyJScript2.js file.

Comment: Just put the SCRIPT element with the ready handler *after* all SCRIPT elements that load external scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is not the order, but that the $(document).ready is executed before the js content is returned, so the function hasn't been loaded yet when it gets called.

The document ready is intended to guarantee the DOM is prepared, not that all the http calls are completed and I'm fairly certain that the usual script blocking doesn't apply in this case.

For what it's worth, I recreated your test and ran it successfully, proving the order doesn't matter and that this is a timing/loading issue: http://havenshade.com/tmp/testalert.html

I didn't find a happy solution though :(

Answer (score 1):

The script tags in the body will likely be executed (or try to be) before the additional requests for the external JS files have completed.

It's less an issue of function declaration order than load order and timing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a script tag to import MyJscript2, you could use [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to grab the script and execute some functionality in the success callback.